# Check whether the two string columns contain each other in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
   id       a       b
0   1     lol   lolec
1   2   rambo     ram
2   3      ki     pio
3   4    iloc     loc
4   5   strip  rstrip
5   6  lambda  lambda
```

I would like to create a new column `c` based on the following criterion：

If `a` is equal or substring of `b` or ***vise versa***, then create a new column `c` with value `1`, otherwise keep it as `0`.

How could I do that in Pandas or Python?

The expected result:

```
   id       a       b  c
0   1     lol   lolec  1
1   2   rambo     ram  1
2   3      ki     pio  0
3   4    iloc     loc  1
4   5   strip  rstrip  1
5   6  lambda  lambda  1
```

To check whether `a` is in `b` or `b` is in `a`, we can use:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.a in x.b, axis=1)
df.apply(lambda x: x.b in x.a, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zip` and list comprehension:

```
df['c'] = [int(a in b or b in a) for a, b in zip(df.a, df.b)]

df
   id       a       b  c
0   1     lol   lolec  1
1   2   rambo     ram  1
2   3      ki     pio  0
3   4    iloc     loc  1
4   5   strip  rstrip  1
5   6  lambda  lambda  1
```

---

Or use `apply`, just combine both conditions with `or`:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda r: int(r.a in r.b or r.b in r.a), axis=1)
```